# Rails: how to get fields of rejected submit form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I got one big form with many fields. There are multiple `select_tag` fields:

```
  -(0..2).to_a.each do |id|
    = select_tag('product[category_ids][]', options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), :prompt=> '-- Select a Category --')
```

**Problem:** If the form is rejected upon submit, the :new action does not remember what is the previous selected values of select_tags.

Every other field reappears after submit (like `:title`, `:description`), but `categories_id` are lost.

**Probable solution:** We must add default selection to the `select_tag` in the `options_from_collection_for_select` method. How to get that `category_id` value? How can we access the fields of the previous form?

```
options_from_collection_for_select(Category.ordered, :id, :name, category_id)
```

Comment: Have you tried your "probable solution"? Did it work? If so, this should be posted in Q&A format.

Comment: This is not exactly a solution, because there is one unknown variable - 'category_id'. My question is: "How I can get that unknown variable?".

Comment: i'd use ajax and submit form with json or `FormData`. If it fails use the response to highlight invalid inputs (you never leave the page so user inputs are retained). If it succeeds return a url in the location header and use `pushState` or `window.location` to redirect. Form should still submit for users without js - they just won't see their original values when it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my form

```
@product.categories = []
```

but

```
@product.category_ids = [1,42,57]
```

So I added one messy `if` statement:

```
-if @product.category_ids.count == 0  #create new product
  -(0..2).to_a.each do |id|
    = select_tag('product[category_ids][]', options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), :prompt=> '-- Select a Category --')
-else  #edit old product, or fixing errors to previous submit
  -@product.category_ids.each do |category_id|
    = select_tag('product[category_ids][]', options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name, category_id), :prompt=> '-- Select a Category --')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store this data in the session and load it in the new action if it exists and clear that from the session.

That way anytime the fields reject the one that is not remembered loads into the session and is loaded into the select on the new action. Otherwise nothing is loaded when this session variable is blank.

Hope this helps.